# String Theory-Virasoro Generators -- show commutator relation

Tags: mathematical-physics, problem-solving, string-theory

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

(I have dropped the hats on the $\alpha_{n}^{u}$ operators and $L_{m}$)

$[\alpha_{n}^u, \alpha_m^v]=n\delta_{n+m}\eta^{uv}$
$L_m=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} : \alpha_{m-n}^u\alpha_{n}^v: \eta_{uv}-\delta_{m,0}$

where " : " denotes normal-ordered.

Show that : $[\alpha_{m}^u,L_n]=m\alpha_{m+n}^u$

2. Relevant equations

see above

3. The attempt at a solution

For a given $n$ we are looking at the following commutator: $[\alpha_m,\alpha_{n-m}\alpha_m]$

to use commutator relation:

$[a,bc]=-a[b,c]-[a,c]b$

$a= \alpha_m, b= \alpha_{n-m}, c= \alpha_m $

$[a,c]=0$, $[b,c]=(n-m)\delta_{n=0}\eta^{uv}$ using (1)

$\implies [\alpha_{m}^u,L_n]=\alpha_m^u(m)\eta^{uv} $ which is wrong...

thanks in advance

Comment: I could understand everything except for the notation $\eta_{\nu\mu}$ and $\eta^{\nu\mu}$. What are these? (I gave the question a go, and ended up with the correct answer multiplied by a factor of $\eta$ whatever that is.)

Comment: thank you for your reply. The minkowski metric to get a scalar : $\eta_{uv}\alpha^u\alpha^v=\alpha.\alpha$

Comment: could you possibly share what you did, or what I have done wrong and point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

First we can expand $L_n$ into its normally ordered form:
\begin{align*}
L_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty:\alpha_{n-i}^u\alpha_i^v:\eta_{uv}-\delta_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1}\alpha_i^v\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{n-i}^u\alpha_i^v\eta_{uv}-\delta_n
\end{align*}

We want to find $[\alpha^u_m, L_n]$. In the derivation below I will use the fact that scalars commute, $[A,B+C] = [A,B]+[A,C]$, and a slightly rearranged version of the multiplication rule: $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$. 
\begin{align*}
[\alpha^u_m, L_n] &= [\alpha^u_m, \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1}\alpha_i^v\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{n-i}^u\alpha_i^v\eta_{uv}-\delta_n]\\
&= [\alpha^u_m, \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1}\alpha_i^v\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{n-i}^u\alpha_i^v\eta_{uv}]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1}[\alpha_m^u, \alpha_i^v\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}]+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[\alpha_m^u, \alpha_{n-i}^u\alpha_{i}^v\eta_{uv}]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1}([\alpha_m^u,\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}]\alpha_i^v+\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}[\alpha_m^u,\alpha_i^v])\\
&\phantom{==} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}([\alpha_m^u,\alpha_{i}^v\eta_{uv}]\alpha_{n-i}^u+\alpha_i^v\eta_{uv}[\alpha_m^u,\alpha_{n-i}^u])\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{-1}(m\delta_{m+(n-i)}\eta^{uu}\eta_{uv}\alpha_i^v+\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}m\delta_{m+i}\eta^{uv})\\
&\phantom{==} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(m\delta_{m+i}\eta^{uv}\eta_{uv}\alpha_{n-i}^u+\alpha_i^v\eta_{uv}m\delta_{m+(n-i)}\eta^{uu})\\
\end{align*}
Without loss of generality suppose $m>0$. (If $m = 0$, the whole thing is $0 = m\alpha_{m+n}^u$ as expected. By symmetry of the equation, you can see that $m<0$ will yield the same result.) Now the sum simplifies to the expression below, as the kronecker delta is always zero for the other components of the sum.
\begin{align*}
[\alpha^u_m, L_n] &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}(\alpha_{n-i}^u\eta_{uv}m\delta_{m+i}\eta^{uv}+\alpha_i^v\eta_{uv}m\delta_{m+(n-i)}\eta^{uu})
\end{align*}
The first component in the expression is non-zero exactly when $i=-m$, and the second component is non-zero when $i=m+n$. Hence you get:
\begin{align*}
[\alpha^u_m, L_n] &= \frac{1}{2}(m\alpha_{m+n}^u\eta_{uv}\eta^{uv}+m\alpha_{m+n}^v\eta_{uv}\eta^{uu})\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(m\alpha_{m+n}^u+m\alpha_{m+n}^u)\\
&= m\alpha_{m+n}^u
\end{align*}
I'm still not confident on what the exact actions of $\eta^{uv}$ and $\eta_{uv}$ are, so I'm not sure if saying $\alpha^v\eta_{uv}\eta^{uu} = \alpha^u$ is correct. Apart from that my derivation should be okay.